# AutoRest is requiring ServiceClientCredentials in the constructor, but I can't obtain that data without instantiating the client object

Tags: c#, swagger, bearer-token, autorest

I generated an API client with AutoRest and am using the `--add-credentials` parameter so that I can pass in a bearer token. In order to get the token, I need to be able to instantiate the object and call my login method like this:

```
var client = new IOIWebAPI(new Uri("https://localhost:44325", UriKind.Absolute));
var loginResult = client.Login(authModel);
```

The problem is that every constructor requires `ServiceClientCredentials`. From what I understand, I need to create an instance of `TokenCredentials`, which includes the token string. But I can't do that because I can't get the token string without calling Login. And I can't call Login without having the token string.

I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding how to consume the API client. But any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that `--add-credentials` does not support unauthenticated endpoints. When you add creds, AutoRest assumes everything needs auth. I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/3268) for this, but I suspect it won't be addressed any time soon.

My workaround was to create a `TokenHelper` class. I copy and pasted the code that AutoRest generated from my login endpoint into that class. So the code stays consistent, but it's not ideal because I may forget to update the endpoint if it ever changes.

```
var tokenHelper = new TokenHelper(baseUri);
var tokenResult = tokenHelper.GetTokenAsync(authModel).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var token = new TokenCredentials(tokenResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
var client = new IOIWebAPI(baseUri, token);
```